# Can someone help me on converting this Kotlin function with callback to a java function?

Tags: java, for-loop, kotlin, functional-programming, jvm

I don't have any exposure to kotlin so far. And so, I find it difficult to understand how this 'callback' works actually. So that, I couldn't figure out how to write this 'callback' feature of kotlin to java.

```
fun stopStream(callback:(text:String)->Unit) {
        if(bidiStream == null) return

        bidiStream?.closeSend()

        for (response in bidiStream!!) {
            val queryResult = response.queryResult

            Log.d(TAG, "Response Text: '${queryResult.responseText}'")
            callback(queryResult.responseText)
        }

        bidiStream = null
        queryInput = null
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know many ides offer such a conversion?

`(text:String)->Unit` takes a `String` and produces nothing, so it's a `Consumer<String>`. Other than that not much changes

```
void stopStream(Consumer<String> callback) {
    if(bidiStream == null) return;

    bidiStream.closeSend();

    for (Response response: bidiStream) {
        var queryResult = response.getQueryResult();

        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Response Text: %s"), queryResult.getResponseText());
        callback(queryResult.getResponseText());
    }

    bidiStream = null;
    queryInput = null;
}
```

Comment: Great!! That was really a quick response. Thank you.